# Edit IF statement using filenames in a column

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a column with filenames:

```
Excel1.xlsx
Excel2.xlsx
Excel3.xlsx
etc
etc
etc
```

and I also have this IF statement:

> =IF('[MainExcel.xlsx]Data'!$C$4='[Excel1.xlsx]Data'!$C$4,IF('[MainExcel.xlsx]Data'!$E$4='[Excel1.xlsx]Data'!$E$4,7,IF('[Excel1.xlsx]Data'!$C$4>'[Excel1.xlsx]Data'!$E$4,5,0)))

So I am trying to comparate an Excel Worksheet (Data) from all these files (Excel1, Excel2, Excel3, etc) with a main Excel (MainExcel)

Any way of doing this without having to change the IF statement one by one in every row?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `concatenate` and `indirect`.

Since I don't know the full layout of your sheet I won't get too in depth but, for example

```
=IF(INDIRECT(CONATENATE("[",A1,"]Data'!$C$4"))=4,TRUE,FALSE)
```

where `A1` is the cell that has the name of the other excel file.

Comment: Nope, not working either...

`=IF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[Main Excel.xlsx]Data'!$C$4='[",A2,"]Data'!$C$4")),IF('[Main Excel.xlsx]Data'!$E$4='[Excel1.xlsx]Data'!$E$4,7,IF('[Excel1.xlsx]Data'!$C$4>'[Excel1.xlsx]Data'!$E$4,5,0)))`

Comment: @randomizertech I'm not going to retype all your nested ifs but make it more like `IF('[MainExcel.xlsx]Data'!$C$4=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[",A1,"]Data'!$C$4")),TRUE,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the INDIRECT function to build references to other workbooks, using cell references.

As an example, that you can build upon.
Assume:

- Excel1.xlsx -> Excel3.xlsx respectively have the values 1, 2, 3 in
  cell A1 on Sheet1,
- All workbooks are open (or else we would have to add path information
- that the file names were in column A

The following entries in column B would pull the appropriate values from the referenced workbooks.

```
=INDIRECT("'["&A1&"]Sheet1'!A1")
```

Comment: Nope, not working with that IF statement described above

Answer (score 0):

Just using what others have said, assuming that the cell containing the first workbook name "Excel1.xlsx" is in cell A1, then try:

```
=IF(Data!$C$4=INDIRECT("["&A1&"]Data!$C$4"),IF(Data!$E$4=INDIRECT("["&A1&"]Data!$E$4"),7,IF(INDIRECT("["&A1&"]Data!$C$4")>INDIRECT("["&A1&"]Data!$E$4"),5,0)))
```

Also, I note that it appears that the case in which the first comparison is false is not covered under your subsequent values (your function just returns the value "false").